# What is the best way to replace 2 possible strings with another string?

Tags: javascript

If the string starts with either `foo.com` or `bar.me` replace with `baz.co`. Is this the most efficient / concise way?

```
string1.replace('foo.com', 'baz.co').replace('bar.me', 'baz.co')
```

We could have an array of strings: `['foo.com', 'bar.me']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
string1.replace(/foo\.com|bar\.me/, 'baz.co')
```

"Starts with" would require to anchor the expression:

```
string1.replace(/^(foo\.com|bar\.me)/, 'baz.co')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the solution of [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71599357/1960455).

A more generalized way to solve such "chained" operations (In case that those can't be expressed with a RegExp) would be to use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) functionality:

```js
let string1 = 'bar.me.test'

string1 = ['foo.com', 'bar.me'].reduce((previousValue, valueFromArray) => {
  return previousValue.replace(valueFromArray, 'baz.co')
}, string1);

console.log(string1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood you question. You would like to replace a couple of strings in an array with "baz.co". You have two arrays. 1) array with multiple strings. 2) array with string which you will replace (needle). And a string which you use for the replacement.

```js
const arr = ['foo.com', 'bar.me', 'not.re'];
const nee = ['foo.com', 'bar.me']
const rep = 'baz.co'
const n = [];

arr.forEach(i => { 
  n.push( nee.includes(i) ? rep : i);
})

console.log(n)
```